# Get likes in python from Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am very new to the Facebook Graph API and Facebook SDK for Python. One of the things I try to get is for a given post on a Facebook page to have all the reactions as dictionaries. 
I tried the get_connections method with the post I’d as parameter and reactions as connection_name parameter but without much luck. Basically the data presented was an empty list and there are 22 reactions for that post. Could this be because of the token permissions?

```
import facebook
post_data = graph.get_connections(id="258795798123414_327571541245839", connection_name="reactions")
print post_data
```

and the result is :

```
 {u'paging': {u'cursors': {u'after': u'QVFIUlNNMWpmZAFYxMjFGLVV6VnF2LUxmQ21qb0pwTHp0LVVMTmpocnQxcDZAFVmFReXRjVmdwRGpFZAlN2SnNoamVSelJac29IdlJZASVZAmYVYyRkdMMjdhWXpB', u'before': u'QVFIUkdWR2VKREJVSEFyVmFDbkxTOUZA4cEI4Y1RXb0VSZAHoyOEdLUjBXdFpMMzNpQzdGUlBPVW9STW80TU5sb21VNG1Ga1M3WktjMGM3TUJpRHlRZA2V2VjBR'}}, u'data': []}
```

Comment: please show us the codes so we can take a look.

Comment: added. Thank you!

Comment: try this: graph.get_connections(id="258795798123414_327571541245839"), connection_name="likes"). Valid values are feed, friends, groups, likes, posts

Comment: I tried that and the result is the same: u'data': []